# "Win32_Printer Where Network = TRUE" return no result in visual studio installer project

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio, installation

Using the following code, I can find and delete the print queue

```
Dim scope = New ManagementScope(ManagementPath.DefaultPath)
scope.Connect()
Dim printers = New ManagementObjectSearcher(scope, New SelectQuery("Select * from Win32_Printer Where Network = TRUE")).[Get]()
MsgBox("Print count: " & printers.Count)
For Each printer As ManagementObject In printers
    Dim nameOfPrinter = printer("Name").ToString()

    If nameOfPrinter.Contains("BROTHER") OrElse nameOfPrinter.Contains("HP") Then
        printer.Delete()
    End If
Next
```

However, when I move the code to installer.vb (which is added to installer project as primary output (active)), the printers.count is returned 0

**UPDATED: if I remove the where cause, I can get the local print queues**

```
<Security.Permissions.SecurityPermission(Security.Permissions.SecurityAction.Demand)> _
    Public Overrides Sub Commit(ByVal savedState As  _
  System.Collections.IDictionary)
Dim scope = New ManagementScope(ManagementPath.DefaultPath)
    scope.Connect()
    Dim printers = New ManagementObjectSearcher(scope, New SelectQuery("Select * from Win32_Printer Where Network = TRUE")).[Get]()
    MsgBox("Print count: " & printers.Count)
    For Each printer As ManagementObject In printers
        Dim nameOfPrinter = printer("Name").ToString()

        If nameOfPrinter.Contains("BROTHER") OrElse nameOfPrinter.Contains("HP") Then
            printer.Delete()
        End If
    Next
```

Is there anything I have missed to add? Please advise, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

The most likely explanation is that network resources printers (and other network items like mapped drive letters) are specific to the user context. In Visual Studio setups that run for Everyone the custom actions run with the local system account (which is required for them to be elevated) so it won't find them. You're asking if the system account has any network printers (and the system account has no network access anyway). It finds the local printers that are hard-wire connected because they are available to all users.

There isn't really a good detour for this in Visual Studio setups. The kind of thing you're doing is often best achieved with a configuration program that runs when the application first runs. It's not clear to me why you want to delete the print queue during an install, but if it's something that might need to be done several times then the user can rerun the program at a later time, and maybe if a printer of that type is installed after your install something might need configuring again.

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can't retrieve printers from "Select * from Win32_Printer Where Network = TRUE" since you are installing the setup to all users of the computer but, you are sharing the network printer to a particular user. I fixed the problem simply sharing the network printer to all the users using 'Run'.

To do that simply,
Go to 'Run' *(winkey + R)* and type
**rundll32 printui.dll,PrintUIEntry /ga /n\servername\printername**
*(please replace the **servername** and **printername** accordingly.
ex:- rundll32 printui.dll,PrintUIEntry /ga /n\100.100.161.48\EPSON LX -310 ESC/P)*
and click 'OK'. Then restart the computer.

The printer will be added to all the users and now you can retrieve network printers from "Select * from Win32_Printer Where Network = TRUE".

I hope this may be helpful.